# How to set the size of a desktop gadget that you create

Tags: html, windows, windows-7, windows-desktop-gadgets

I am trying to create a very basic windows desktop gadget to display my Stack Overflow Flair.

I do not have much experience with html or web development. I have tried to follow the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but when I install the gadget it is tiny:

[image]

Yes, it's that tiny white square.

I have tried setting a background image but it doesn't seem to work either (I don't actually need a background image, I was just trying to get it to work). If I run the html source file stand alone then it displays correctly in a browser:

[image]

Here is the code from the html source file (named MySOFlair.html):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="gadgetContent">
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2012446/chrisprosser">
        <img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2012446.png" width="208" height="58" 
             alt="profile for ChrisProsser at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" 
             title="profile for ChrisProsser at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers"/>
      </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code from the manifest file (Gadget.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<gadget>
  <name>MySOFlair</name>
  <version>1.0.0.0</version>
  <author name="Chris Prosser" />
  <description>Mt Stack Overflow Flair Gadget</description>
  <!--<icons>
    <icon src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2012446.png" 
          width="208" 
          height="58" />
  </icons>-->
  <hosts>
    <host name="sidebar">
      <base type="HTML" apiVersion="1.0.0" src="MySOFlair.html" />
      <permissions>Full</permissions>
      <platform minPlatformVersion="1.0" />
      <!--<defaultImage src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2012446.png" 
                    width="208" 
                    height="58"/>-->
    </host>
  </hosts>
</gadget>
```

I have tried uncommenting the image links in here, but it doesn't change anything.

Any ideas on how to set the size correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found how to fix this. I found a style element that could be inserted into the HTML header section. Here is the new HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
       margin:  0;
       width: 212;
       height: 62;
    }
    #gadgetContent
    {
       margin:  0px;
       width: 208px;
       height: 58px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="gadgetContent">
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2012446/chrisprosser">
        <img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2012446.png" width="208" height="58" 
             alt="profile for ChrisProsser at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" 
             title="profile for ChrisProsser at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers"/>
      </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```